# Nsapplescript open file

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

I have the following code:

```
NSAppleScript* playPause = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:
               @"tell application \"Xcode\"to activate \n to open POSIX file \"beetSapper.xcodeproj""\n"
               @"end tell"];   
[playPause executeAndReturnError:NULL];
```

However it is not opening the file "beetSapper"  I guess the way I am writing the string is not working. Can somebody show how to write this command properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many `to`s in the code.

Since Xcode accepts also POSIX paths you can write

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate
    open "/Users/myUser/Documents/beetSapper.xcodeproj/"
end tell
```

The "stringyfied" equivalent is

```
"tell application \"Xcode\"\n activate\n open \"/Users/myUser/Documents/beetSapper.xcodeproj/\"\n end tell"
```

Be aware that you have to specify the full path to the project file starting with a slash.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind can you show me how to write an if statement in here.  I guess I need to know how to write a new "line". For instance, does "\n" means next line? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, `\n` means a new line, it's the escaped (`\`) newline character (`0x0a`)

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Xcode"
  open file "Macintosh HD:Users:YourUserName:YourFolder:YourFolder:YourFileProject.xcodeproj"
end tell
```